# JWT ValidateToken overriding in C#

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api2, claims-based-identity, jwt

I have setup a token authentication process and its working quite well. I am using OWIN.

I am extending 2 specific points which lets me control the signing of the JWT and also the validating of user credentials like so.

```
            Provider = new MyOAuthProvider(),
            AccessTokenFormat = new MyJwtFormatter()
```

How do I hook into the part where the token is being validated. I searched the web and it appears there is a method can't ValidateToken that you can override but I don't know where this is.

I also have the following. Do I need to override something here ?

```
        app.UseJwtBearerAuthentication(
            new JwtBearerAuthenticationOptions
                {
                    AuthenticationMode = AuthenticationMode.Active,
                    AllowedAudiences = new[] { audience },
                    IssuerSecurityTokenProviders =
                        new IIssuerSecurityTokenProvider[]
                            {
                                new SymmetricKeyIssuerSecurityTokenProvider(
                                    issuer,
                                    secret)
                            }
                });
```

What might I be missing? Most of the things I have found support what I am doing but not hooking into the token authentication.

I believe its using the internal JWTTokenHandler, I presume you can override this or something?

Answer (score 0):

Here's simple JWT Validation class based on: [Google Sign-In for Websites](https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/backend-auth#send-the-id-token-to-your-server)

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IdentityModel.Tokens;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Configuration;
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using System.Net;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Threading;
using Services.Models;
using System.Security.Claims;

namespace Services
{
    /// <summary>
    ///  This is an implementation of Google JWT verification that
    ///  demonstrates:
    ///    - JWT validation
    /// </summary>
    /// @author kunal.bajpai@gmail.com (Kunal Bajpai)


    public class CustomJwtHandler : DelegatingHandler
    {
        string issuer = WebConfigurationManager.AppSettings["GoogleDomain"];
        string audience = WebConfigurationManager.AppSettings["GoogleClientId"];

        /// <summary>
        /// 
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="request"></param>
        /// <param name="cancellationToken"></param>
        /// <returns></returns>
        protected override Task<HttpResponseMessage> SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
        {
            HttpStatusCode statusCode;
            string token;

            var authHeader = request.Headers.Authorization;
            if (authHeader == null)
            {
                // Missing authorization header
                return base.SendAsync(request, cancellationToken);
            }

            if (!TryRetrieveToken(request, out token))
            {
                return Task<HttpResponseMessage>.Factory.StartNew(() => new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized));
            }

            try
            {
                ValidateToken(token);
                return base.SendAsync(request, cancellationToken);
            }
            catch (SecurityTokenInvalidAudienceException)
            {
                statusCode = HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized;
            }
            catch (SecurityTokenValidationException)
            {
                statusCode = HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized;
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                statusCode = HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError;
            }

            return Task<HttpResponseMessage>.Factory.StartNew(() => new HttpResponseMessage(statusCode));
        }
        /// <summary>
        /// Validates JWT Token
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="token"></param>
        private void ValidateToken(string token)
        {
            try
            {
                using (WebClient wc = new WebClient())
                {
                    TokenInfo tokenInfo = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<TokenInfo>(wc.DownloadString("https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v3/tokeninfo?id_token=" + token));

                    List<Claim> claims = new List<Claim> {
                        new Claim(ClaimTypes.Name, tokenInfo.Name),
                        new Claim(ClaimTypes.Email, tokenInfo.Email),
                        new Claim(ClaimTypes.GivenName, tokenInfo.GivenName),
                        new Claim(ClaimTypes.Surname, tokenInfo.FamilyName),
                    };

                    ClaimsPrincipal claimsPrincipal = new ClaimsPrincipal(new ClaimsIdentity(claims, tokenInfo.Issuer));
                    Thread.CurrentPrincipal = claimsPrincipal;
                    HttpContext.Current.User = claimsPrincipal;
                }
            }
            catch (WebException e)
            {
                HttpStatusCode statusCode = ((HttpWebResponse)e.Response).StatusCode;
                if (statusCode == HttpStatusCode.BadRequest)
                {
                    throw new SecurityTokenValidationException();
                }
                else
                {
                    throw new Exception();
                }
            }
        }
        /// <summary>
        /// Tries to retrieve Token
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="request"></param>
        /// <param name="token"></param>
        /// <returns></returns>
        private static bool TryRetrieveToken(HttpRequestMessage request, out string token)
        {
            token = null;
            IEnumerable<string> authorizationHeaders;

            if (!request.Headers.TryGetValues("Authorization", out authorizationHeaders) ||
            authorizationHeaders.Count() > 1)
            {
                return false;
            }

            var bearerToken = authorizationHeaders.ElementAt(0);
            token = bearerToken.StartsWith("Bearer ") ? bearerToken.Substring(7) : bearerToken;
            return true;
        }
    }
}
```